# Sails.js disconnects itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I got some trouble with sails.js and socket.io. 
After a little time without use website the socket disconnects itself.

I got the classic error :

```html
La connexion avec ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=XfNvq0iSTWIg564BAAAB a été interrompue pendant le chargement de la page.
sails.io.js (ligne 5)
====================================
sails.io.js (ligne 141)
Socket was disconnected from Sails.
sails.io.js (ligne 141)

Usually, this is due to one of the following reasons:
 -> the server was taken down
 -> your browser lost internet connectivity

sails.io.js (ligne 141)
====================================
sails.io.js (ligne 141)

        Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails...
_-|>_-  (attempt #1)

sails.io.js (ligne 141)
GET http://localhost:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_v...script&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1431665759996-3
 
200 OK
  1ms 
sails.io.js (ligne 4)

  |>    Socket reconnected successfully after
\___/   being offline for ~1.017 seconds.

sails.io.js (ligne 141)
GET http://localhost:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_v...lling&t=1431665760011-4&sid=0_H09meFWxjaSLRPAAAC
 
200 OK
  0ms 
sails.io.js (ligne 4)


  |>    Now connected to Sails.
\___/   For help, see: http://bit.ly/1DmTvgK
        (using browser SDK @v0.11.0)
```

Sails says it connected successfully but if I try to refresh or anything it disconnects again... I must lift again to reconnect correctly.

Someone have an idea what to do, or what can cause this kind of problem?